# Recursive replacement of matching tags with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

`<?foo?> <?bar?> <?baz?> hello world <?/?> <?/?> <?/?>`

I need a regular expression to convert it into

`<?foo?> <?bar?> <?baz?> hello world <?/baz?> <?/bar?> <?/foo?>`

The following code works for non-recursive tags:

```
$x=preg_replace_callback('/.*?<\?\/\?>/',function($x){
    return preg_replace('/(.*<\?([^\/][\w]+)\?>)(.*?)(<\?\/?\?>)/s',
          '\1\3<?/\2?>',$x[0]);
},$str);
```

Comment: My eyes... they are bleeding...

Comment: I have decided to abandon <?/?> closing tags and always require user to name closing tags. That will make it easier for me to to parse them and certainly much faster, because i wouldn't need to rely on going through them manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with regular expressions. You need to write a parser!

So create a stack (an array where you add and remove items from the end. use `array_push()` `array_pop()` ).

Iterate through the tags, pushing known opening tags on the stack.

When you come to a closing tag, pop the stack and that will tell you the tag you need to close.

Comment: Because you need a parser to parse arbitrary nested hierarchies. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

For a recursive structure, make a recursive function. In some form of pseudo-code:

```
tags = ['<?foo?>', '<?bar?>', '<?baz?>']

// output consumed stream to 'output' and return the rest
function close_matching(line, output) {
  for (tag in tags) {
    if line.startswith(tag) {
      output.append(tag)
      line = close_matching(line.substring(tag.length()), output)
      i = line.indexof('<')
      ... // check i for not found
      output.append(line.substring(0, i))
      j = line.indexof('>')
      ... // check j for error, and check what's between i,j is valid for close tag
      output.append(closetag_for_tag(tag))
      line = line.substring(j + 1)
    }
  }
  return line;
}
```

This should give you a basic structure that works.

Comment: This should match any tags, pre-defining all possible tags is not option. Also this would fail with the text containing `<` (not `<?`) too

Comment: Recursion uses the call stack. Iteration uses an implicit stack.